# How to get rewards for each user in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I'm having 3 tables. users, rewards, and gained rewards.
I want to get the rewards for each colleague of the user.

I wrote the following api, but it didn't work.

```
    public function getColleaguesGainedRewards(Request $request){
        $company_id = $request->company_id;
        $colleagues = GainedReward::find(1)->users->where('company_id', $company_id);
        $rewards = GainedReward::all();

        return response()->json([
            "status" => "success",
            $colleagues => $rewards,
        ], 200);
    }
```

And I assigned the following relationship in the gained reward model:

```
    public function users()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(User::class, 'company_id');
    }
    public function rewards()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Reward::class, 'id');
    }
```

The users table looks as follow:

| id | name | company_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John | 1 |
| 2 | Jack | 1 |
| 3 | Alex | 2 |

The companies table looks as follow:

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Abc |
| 2 | Def |

The rewards table looks as follow:

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Day Off |
| 2 | Coffee |

The gained_rewards table looks as follow:

| id | reward_id | user_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 2 | 2 |

So I want to get all the rewards for each colleague.
For example the result should look as follows:

Get the rewards for each employee at company "Abc":

| John | Jack |
| --- | --- |
| Day Off | Day Off |
|  | Coffee |

Comment: Do you know about joining tables in SQL? You can join `users` and `rewards` tables through a pivot table in your case `gained_rewards`.

Answer (score 0):

From what i understood you want to get the users by company ID and for each user you want the gained_rewards and rewards

You should add the relationship for gained_rewards inside the users model

```
public function gainedRewards()
{
    return $this->hasMany(GainedRewards::class, ‘id’,'user_id');
}
```

You can also add the rewards relationship inside of the GainedRewards model

```
public function rewards()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Reward::class, 'id', 'reward_id');
}
```

Then when you do a

```
    $user = User::where('company_id', $request->company_id)->with([
        'gainedRewards' => function($query){},
        'gainedRewards.rewards' => function($query) {}
     ])->get();
```

you can do loop through each user and get the gainedRewards for that user and the rewards

Comment: It returned the following message "Property [gainedRewards] does not exist on this collection instance."

Comment: was gainedRewards function added in the user model to create the relationship? can you show me screenshots of what your user model looks like?

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/z51cBLL @Yeak

Comment: Modified the gainedrewards relationship since id is primary key on users table and user_id is the link in the gained rewards

Answer (score 0):

Grouping per user_id and storing each reward_id into an associative array is one solution which I have implemented recently

```
$groupedRewards = array();

$gainedRewards = \App\GainedReward::all();

foreach ($gainedRewards as $gainedReward) {
  $obj = array('reward_id' => $gainedReward->reward_id);

  if (array_search($gainedReward->user_id, array_column($groupedRewards, 'user_id')) !== false) {
    $the_key = array_search($gainedReward->user_id, array_column($groupedRewards, 'user_id'));
    $rewards = $groupedRewards[$the_key]['rewards'];

    array_push($rewards, $obj);

    $groupedRewards[$the_key]['rewards'] = $rewards;
  }
  else {
    array_push($groupedRewards, array('user_id' => gainedReward->user_id, 'rewards' => array($obj)));
  }
}

echo '<pre>' , var_dump($groupedRewards) , '</pre>';
```

Then you can parse any data you need

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($groupedRewards); $i++) {
  echo '<pre>' , var_dump($groupedRewards[$i]->user_id) , '</pre>';
  for ($j = 0; $j < count(groupedRewards[$i]->rewards); $j++) {
    ...
  }
}
```